# How to add description for a repository in Gitolite configuration

Tags: git, repository, gitolite

I am using gitolite for user maintenance for my GIT server. Everything works fine except repo description. I have setup the description for a repo like "reponame = repo description" in gitolite.conf. Earlier version (before v3.x) its working. Now its not working. For your information I am using

- gitolite v3.1
- GIT v1.7.1
- Perl v5.10.1

Here is my gitolite.conf file http://pastebin.com/DYCK3uRL or http://arulraj.net/gitolite.conf. The post-receive-email mail subject and signature not have description because of that repo description file not generated automatically using gitolite. How can I fix this..?

Comment: The settings described in http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2/confother_.html didn't help?

Comment: @VonC Please have a look my gitolite.conf file in above link. I have added the description in that conf file. But its not working

Comment: Sorry, I was at work, and pastebin is blocked at work. Do you see put the description in `$repo/description`, and if not, for testing only, can you add a `description` file in one of your repo to see if that is enough? That won't explain why gitolite doesn't do it automatically, but it will make sure the description mechanism is working.

Comment: I added description file manually. That description mechanism working fine. But I want to automate this file creation using gitolite. Thanks

Comment: At work again, so no access to pastebin. Are you description lines starting at the very beginning of the line? (asking because of the regexp used by gitolite to extract said description: https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/convert-gitosis-conf#L57-L58)

Comment: Have a look at the script/gitolite command `desc`: https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/commands/desc . Try showing the description of a repo (`ssh git@host desc <repo>`), or setting one through this script (`ssh git@host desc <repo> <description string>`) and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Check also what `gitolite info -ld [<repo name pattern>]` returns: it is supposed to display the description of the repo. (https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/commands/info)

Comment: Those scripts (https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/triggers/post-compile/update-description-file, and https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/triggers/post-compile/update-gitweb-access-list) could be responsible for those description files not being created in the repos. Setting `gitweb.description` might not be compatible with setting repo description.

Comment: You can find find my gitolite.conf from here http://arulraj.net/gitolite.conf . I am checking other possibilities those you are referred. Thanks

Comment: Try removing the `config gitweb.description` lines, just to see if the description files *then* get generated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am happy to say its fixed now. I added this https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/triggers/post-compile/update-description-file script in gitolite post_compile section.

1.Open the **.gitolite.rc** file in HOME directory and edit post_compile section.

```
    POST_COMPILE                =>
    [
        'post-compile/ssh-authkeys',
        'post-compile/update-git-configs',
        'post-compile/update-gitweb-access-list',
        'post-compile/update-git-daemon-access-list',
        'post-compile/update-description-file',
    ],
```

2.Then add description for repo in gitolite.conf. Please refer the below

```
repo    testing
RW+     =   @all
desc = "GIT testing"
```

3.Then commit and push your changes.

Now the description is automatically created. My new conf file here http://pastebin.com/c8Ggfbdi or http://arulraj.net/gitolite.conf.new .

Answer (score 5):

As of gitolite 3.5, you don't have to put the `POST_COMPILE` stuff. Just as enable the `"cgit"` option with `ENABLE => [ 'cgit' ]`. And you run the gitolite setup, then the `.git/description` files will be created with value from `gitweb.description` option.

Answer (score 2):

From [adding a description to repos you created](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/user.html#desc)

```
ssh git@host desc -h
```

[Watch out the `WRITER_CAN_UPDATE_DESC` setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25662289/305189) to avoid the "FATAL: you are not authorized" error.