# Gitolite 3 - Setting repo description (not authorized)

Tags: git, gitolite

I'm using Gitolite 3.6

```
$ ssh git@host info
hello you, this is got@Git running gitolite3 v3.6.1-6-gdc8b590 on git 1.7.10.4
[...]
R W   my_project
[...]
```

Following the documentation on [setting the repo description](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/user.html#desc)

```
$ ssh git@host desc my_project "Machin chouette"
FATAL: you are not authorized
```

How can this be explained ?

---

```
git@host $ cat ~/.gitolite.rc
[...]
    ENABLE => [
        [...]
        'desc',
        'cgit',
    ]
[...]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found what was missing by reading the code of the `desc` command (didn't see it in the doc)

```
git@host $ nano ~/.gitolite.rc
%RC = (
    [...]
    WRITER_CAN_UPDATE_DESC          => 1,
    [...]
)
```

Comment: Good find. I also found the documentation particularly lacking in that regard.